# C# Update Object Properties without breaking instance

Tags: c#

I want to update an instance with properties of a newly created object at once but not breaking the instance binding to other variables. For eg.

```
public class MyClass{
   public double X;
   public double Y;
}

MyClass a = new MyClass(2,1);
MyClass b = a;

MyClass c = new MyClass(1,1);

a = c; //'b' should also be equal to 'a'.
//I dont want to do something like this:
a.Y = c.Y;
a.X = c.X;
```

In my code, 'b' is actually not accessible anymore because it is binded to some UI, 'a' is my only way through updating 'b'. So after 'a = c' is called, b should have the location of [1,1].

Comment: a bit baffled by your use of 'Location here : in WinForms, 'Location is a Property, not a Type; is this in WPF (which I understand does not use the 'Location keyword) ? If in WPF, please tag. thanks,

Comment: fixed it, It can be an object of any kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experimental : please feel free to "blow this out of the water" :) Tested in VS 2010 beta 2 against FrameWork 4.0 and 3.5 (full, not "client" versions).

```
private class indirectReference
{
    // using internal so Loc is not visible outside the class
    internal struct Loc
    {
        public double X;
        public double Y;
    }

    // publicly exposed access to the internal struct
    public Loc pairODoubles;

    // ctor
    public indirectReference(double x, double y)
    {
        pairODoubles.X = x;
        pairODoubles.Y = y;
    }
}

// test ...

indirectReference r1 = new indirectReference(33, 33);

indirectReference r2 = r1;

indirectReference r3 = new indirectReference(66, 66);

// in this case the doubles in r2 are updated 
r1.pairODoubles = r3.pairODoubles;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
class Wrapper
{
    public Wrapper(Location l)
    {
        this.L = l;
    }
    public Location L;
}

Wrapper a = new Wrapper(new Location(2,1));
Wrapper b = a;
Location c = new Location(1,1);
a.L = c;
```

I'm not sure whether it's really appropriate without more context.  Just add a level of indirection.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think making the `MyClass` [immutable](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/01/13/immutable-types-understand-them-and-use-them.aspx) would be a suitable approach?

Or: you should perform some reference counting, through a wrapper.